# dplyr filter data.frame with multiple criteria

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame with columns. I want to return a sub-data frame that is filtered off from the original one by multiple conditions. My first questionis that I want to filter by two of the columns: One column contains discrete values and i want to filter rows that contain the value "Open". The other column contain date values and i want to compound-filter for rows that is equal to a given date

This is my filtering function, using dplyr

```
agendaReq <- function(recTable, agendaDate)
{

  openTable <- filter(recTable, recTable$reqStatus == "Open") 
  agendaTable <- filter(openTable, recTable$reqDate == agendaDate)
  return (agendaTable)

}
```

However, when I call this function in my server as following

```
agendaToShow <- agendaReq(recordTable_CA, Sys.Date())
```

I got this error

```
Warning: Error in : Result must have length 14, not 16
  56: <Anonymous>
Error : Result must have length 14, not 16
```

There are 16 rows in the original data frame. The correct filter should give me 14 rows. But what does this error means?

Finally, how do I do the same for a mix of discrete and continuous variables? (say, filtering based on gender, height, etc...)

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `recTable$` within dplyr verb functions, just the column names directly. It might be beneficial to go through the tutorials and vignettes at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and all necessary code.

Comment: Thanks for the source. I will check it out.

Answer (score 4):

Without a small reproducible example of your data, it is difficult ot be sure that it is working but did you try:

```r
library(dplyr)
recTable %>% filter(reqStatus == "Open" & reqDate == agendaDate)
```

If this is not working, please consider to provide a reproducible example of your data as described here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm often torn between the R-idiomatic logic of `&` and the `dplyr`-idiomatic way of implicit "and" by way of `filter(reqStatus == "Open", reqDate == agendaDate)`. They both work, of course, and there's no direct `dplyr`-idiomatic way of "or", so perhaps the explicit use of `&` provides a consistent and declarative manner. \*shrug\*

Comment: Actually, I didn't know that `filter(reqStatus == "Open", reqDate == agendaDate)` was working too ;) thanks for pointing that. I like the `&` because it is really easy to understand (and oppositely, I hate the `%in%` I can't get to remember it even if it is super-useful to know it)

Comment: `%in%` is not needed here, though it would also work. As for comma-separated, it's used in many of the examples on https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html (and in `?filter`).

Comment: Good to know ! (I was not mentioning %in% for the current response but as an example of the kind of symbols that I found strange to use. But you're right, it's out of focus)

Comment: Thanks. This works. Also, I found what is wrong with my code. In the second filter, I should use ```openTable$reqDate``` instead of the original table. But your solution is much better.

Comment: Glad that it helps you ;)